# Round outdoor junction (not flush) to square

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have seen square to round adapters for junction boxes but not round to square.  I have an outdoor mounted round junction box with a light that's mounted on the wall not in it.  I want to convert it to a square so I can put a square light backed light in instead.  Is there a converter?  I'd rather not rip it out and put more holes in the stucco plus the wires are coming in from conduit from the side so it's more of a pain.

Comment: Can you post photos of the situation?

Comment: I agree, we need more information about what's going on in this setup.  It seems *very* unusual.  Any chance this is involving a score off Amazon Marketplace, eBay or Ali Express?

Comment: Can you post a pic of the light too?

Comment: I know this is not what you want to hear but, Conduit should be no problem you can just unscrew the nut on the conduit or Unsnap. Since the box is surface mounted it should be simple to remove it and replace with a box that is rated for a wet location like a 4 square bell box. Most of the box adapters I have used are nema 1 and it would need to be 3r for outdoor use.

Comment: Nothing overly complicated!  I just have one of these mounted to the outside of my wall:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Greenfield-4-in-Round-Weatherproof-Electrical-Outlet-Box-with-Five-1-2-in-Holes-Bronze-RB25BRS/202188683?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CAll-Products%7CAll%7CAll%7CPLA%7c71700000014585962%7c58700001236285396%7c92700010802552412&gclid=CjwKCAjwyqTqBRAyEiwA8K_4O-e4VlF9mggC7aKKMjymfevwWJ1bRIyIvvpnc4xYzz8dgfXPVrz0AxoCpjAQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

but want to convert it to square so but without having to take it off and make more holes.  the conduit comes in from the side.